# Rails 2: helper for passing classes to body tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote a small helper which adds controller and action name as classes to the body tag of application.html.erb

```
// helper
def body_classes
  [controller_name, action_name].join(' ')
end

// layout
<% content_tag :body, :class => body_classes do %>
......
<% end %>
```

Now I'm looking for a way to determine if the corresponding controller is capsuled into a subdirectory:

```
/controller
  /my_subdir
    /user_controller.rb
```

if true I want to pass the subdir name as third class to my helper, something like module_name. Any advice how to achieve this? I'm still bound to Rails 2.3.18 here, but it should work with Rails 3 likewise.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `module_name`, however, you could use `controller.controller_path.parameterize` to get the name of the controller together with the module it belongs to.

In your case you would get 'my_subdir-users'.

Hope that helps